# Excel Conditional Formatting with Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to highlight cells in column A whose corresponding values in column B meet a certain criteria. I followed some ways but none leaded to anything. I just want to highlight cells in column A whose values in column B are greater than 100.
[image: The Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column A with A1 as the active cell then create a CFR based on the following formula.

```
=and($b1>100, row()>1)
```

Comment: Could you explain the reason why you added the second condition: row()>1 ?

Comment: You have text as column header labels and I didn't want any confusion.